# How to reduce size of SQL Server table that grew from a datatype change

Tags: sql-server, types, database-table

I have a table on SQL Server 2005 that was about 4gb in size.

(about 17 million records)

I changed one of the fields from datatype `char(30)` to `char(60)` (there are in total 25 fields most of which are `char(10)` so the amount of char space adds up to about 300)

This caused the table to double in size (over 9gb)

I then changed the `char(60)` to `varchar(60)` and then ran a function to cut extra whitespace out of the data (so as to reduce the average length of the data in the field to about 15)

This did not reduce the table size. Shrinking the database did not help either.

Short of actually recreating the table structure and copying the data over (that's 17 million records!) is there a less drastic way of getting the size back down again?

Comment: How exactly did you shrink the database?

Comment: in management studio.  

Tasks->Shrink->Files->Release unused space

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well it's clear you're not getting any space back ! :-)

When you changed your text fields to CHAR(60), they are all filled up to capacity with spaces. So ALL your fields are now really 60 characters long.

Changing that back to VARCHAR(60) won't help - the fields are still all 60 chars long....

What you really need to do is run a TRIM function over all your fields to reduce them back to their trimmed length, and then do a database shrinking.

After you've done that, you need to REBUILD your clustered index in order to reclaim some of that wasted space. The clustered index is really where your data lives - you can rebuild it like this:

```
ALTER INDEX IndexName ON YourTable REBUILD
```

By default, your primary key is your clustered index (unless you've specified otherwise).

Marc

Comment: I did that... "ran a function to cut extra whitespace out of the data"

Comment: specifically I did update table [table] set [column] = replace([column],' ','') where year = 2009 

(then again for 2008, 2007, and so on)

Comment: Have you tried       UPDATE Table SET Column = RTRIM(Column)    across all years? Still no change?

Comment: All years at once?  Or all years one year at a time?  I'm currently trying it one year at a time

Comment: Right. I did that.  It made no difference,

Comment: what if I do "Empty file by migrating the data to other files in the same filegroup"

Comment: You need to rebuild your clustered index to reclaim (at least some of) the wasted space. Worked for me.

Comment: SUCCESS!!   That worked.  I'll tick yours as the answer that worked.  I really appreciate this not only because you've helped me fix it, but you've also increased my knowledge.

Answer (score 29):

You have not cleaned or compacted any data, even with a "shrink database".

[DBCC CLEANTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418.aspx)

> Reclaims space from dropped variable-length columns in tables or indexed views.

However, a [simple index rebuild](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388(SQL.90).aspx) *if there is a clustered index* should also do it

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.Mytable REBUILD
```

[A worked example from Tony Rogerson](https://web.archive.org/web/20170629065414/http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2007/08/27/alter-table-drop-column-does-not-reclaim-the-space-the-column-took-it-s-a-meta-data-change-only.aspx)

Comment: Thanks also to you for providing the answer.  though I saw the other guy's first.  Sorry. :)

Comment: Thanks. Although I added my answer within minutes of his revision: his first answer did not mention index rebuild

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm not answering your question as you are asking, but have you considered archiving some of the data to a history table, and work with fewer rows?

Most of the times you might think at first glance that you need all that data all the time but when actually sitting down and examining it, there are cases where that's not true. Or at least I've experienced that situation before.

Comment: 11 years later I randomly found this old question.  Giving your answer an upvote as I did end up doing this very thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem here [SQL Server, Converting NTEXT to NVARCHAR(MAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487324/sql-server-converting-ntext-to-nvarcharmax) that was related to changing ntext to nvarchar(max).

I had to do an `UPDATE MyTable SET MyValue = MyValue` in order to get it to resize everything nicely.

This obviously takes quite a long time with a lot of records. There were a number of suggestions as how better to do it. They key one was a temporary flag indicated if it had been done or not and then updating a few thousand at a time in a loop until it was all done. This meant I had "some" control over how much it was doing.

On another note though, if you really want to shrink the database as much as possible, it can help if you turn the recovery model down to simple, shrink the transaction logs, reorganise all the data in the pages, then set it back to full recovery model. Be careful though, shrinking of databases is generally not advisable, and if you reduce the recovery model of a live database you are asking for something to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do a full table rebuild to ensure there's no extra data hanging around anywhere:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table(<column definitions>);
GO
INSERT INTO tmp_table(<columns>) SELECT <columns> FROM <table>;
GO
DROP TABLE <table>;
GO
EXEC sp_rename N'tmp_table', N'<table>';
GO
```

Of course, things get more complicated with identity, indexes, etc etc...

Comment: This might be a little easier:

SELECT * INTO tmp_table FROM my_table
GO
DROP TABLE my_table
GO
EXEC sp_rename N'tmp_table', N'my_table';
GO

Comment: Agree with Beach's comment above. In addition to it being easier, it avoids using the logging the transaction when you select * into NewTable so should be much faster.