# Do extra spaces affect disk space?

Tags: sql-server, storage, varchar

I have 147 columns in a database with the majority of them as VARCHAR. This data is imported in from a government agency and for empty fields, they include all the spaces the field allows instead of just entering an empty string or NULL. Some fields are 50 characters of just spaces.

I recently ran a script that converted all of those columns with just spaces to use NULL instead, but the table storage size remained the exact same.

I would have thought that spaces would have taken up a lot of disk space (we have 60 million records). But no difference was made.

Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: Did you "compact" the database afterwards?

Comment: Once the entries are created, they most likely retain that space, even if less of it is actually "used". Which is why user2864740 suggested compaction.

Comment: The following SO Q/A seems to address your scenario   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807579/how-to-reduce-size-of-sql-server-table-that-grew-from-a-datatype-change

Comment: If they're zerofill then it's just a flag on the columns.

Comment: @joshstrike - This is SQL Server. Not MySQL.

Comment: @bigronaldo: how did you  measure table size before and after?

Comment: I shrank the database, but that didn't make a difference. However, once I followed adkSerenity's link to a previous question, I saw that I need to rebuild my clustered index. Once I did that, it shrunk the size quite it bit (roughly 35%).

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to rebuild my clustered index for the table.

```
ALTER INDEX IndexName ON YourTable REBUILD
```

This was answered by adkSerenity in the link he provided in his above comment.

[How to reduce size of SQL Server table that grew from a datatype change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807579/how-to-reduce-size-of-sql-server-table-that-grew-from-a-datatype-change)