# Differences in Table size

Tags: sql-server

I have to check big tables on our SQL Server and shrink these tables if possible. See select below.
One table is about 18 GB. This big table contains a column of type Image which stores binary data.

```
    SELECT 
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS Zeilenanzahl,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS [Total Storage], 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS [Used Storage], 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS [Free Storage]
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE   
     t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    [Total Storage] desc, s.Name, t.Name
```

If I check the image field I get about 700 MB.

```
  select sum( datalength(Property))
    from dbo.TIF_UserDWProperty
```

I have checked the actual Size with this:

```
select * into NewTable
  from dbo.TIF_UserDWProperty
```

The newly created table has the correct size of about 700 MB.

Where does this difference came from? 
How can I shrink this table? 
I have tried DBCC SHRINKDATABASE with no success.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807579/how-to-reduce-size-of-sql-server-table-that-grew-from-a-datatype-change

Comment: Your new table doesn't have any indexes on `TIF_UserDWProperty`. I suspect they are the things that bloat it to 18GB.

Comment: Thanks, good hint. I have cloned this table (fields and indexes). If I insert same data, the size of cloned table is correct. I have to mention, that there are many deletes and updates on this table. Can this image field cause this problem?