# Convert column nText to nvarchar(1026)

Tags: sql-server

I need to change my column datatype from `nText null` to `nvarchar(1026) null`.
I have used the below query(Sql server).

```
ALTER TABLE [Tablename] ALTER COLUMN [Columnname] nvarchar(1026) null
```

while executing the query, I am getting the following issue:

> Cannot alter column of type NTEXT or IMAGE [ Column Name = Columnname]

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/0e1dc68a-cb6d-44be-af9c-30095a760b79/cannot-alter-column-of-type-ntext-or-image

Comment: Above comment asks you to download a tool - there really isn't the need to. The link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487324/sql-server-converting-ntext-to-nvarcharmax) tells you how to do this, even advise you how to do it if you cannot arrange down time.

Comment: select max(len(convert(nvarchar(max),Columnname))) from Tablename tell me the result of this query

Comment: did you try ALTER TABLE [Tablename] ALTER COLUMN [Columnname] nvarchar(max) null ????

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL statement is working fine in Sql Server 2014.

I believe you have to perform several steps.

1. Create a new column in your table

   ```
   ALTER TABLE [Tablename] ADD [NewCol] nvarchar(1026) null
   ```
2. Copy original column content to the new column using `UPDATE` and `CONVERT`

   ```
   UPDATE [Tablename] SET NewCol=CONVERT(nvarchar(1026), Columnname)
   ```
3. Drop original column

   ```
   ALTER TABLE [Tablename] drop column [Columnname]
   ```
4. Rename new column back to the original name

   ```
   Exec sp_rename 'Tablename.NewCol', 'Columnname', 'Column'
   ```

Comment: also need to check the max size of the data in old ntext column it should be less than 1026